# How can I get a value from an Arraylist<String>?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to add some strings *("oidfb9we923982" as some ID)* within at specific index *(82, "ojnfonfw7")* but I can't get it to work.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 82, size is 1
```

I think that the best way to explain is giving some example,

```
//MARILYNMANSON
ArrayList<String> mMarilynManson = new ArrayList<String>();

mMarilynManson.add(82,"d5c820e90ab46626aed6fg70038424b63f");
mMarilynManson.add(83,"410862c61aa32b14419c43dsf03e84a42f");
mMarilynManson.add(84,"922e09adc85b9c9dd5bgg75b84d809c5f3");
```

I was trying to make loopings to create until 100, and different ways but no one works... any buddy could give me a hand?

Thanks you very much!

Comment: show us the code for your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a `HashMap` instead if you want the behavior of an associative array.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> mMarilynManson = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

mMarilynManson.put(82,"d5c820e90ab46626aed6fg70038424b63f");
mMarilynManson.put(83,"410862c61aa32b14419c43dsf03e84a42f");
mMarilynManson.put(84,"922e09adc85b9c9dd5bgg75b84d809c5f3");
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `ArrayList` API:

`IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())`

Your `List` size is 0 so you can't insert element at greater index.

Comment: Yes i know, but I need to resolve it! can you give me some answer please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really want do this you can loop until 100 then do as you like but it will be slower and for your use case hashtable would be better

```
for(int i = 0;i < 100;i++ ){
   mMarilynManson.add("meme");}
mMarilynManson.add(82,"d5c820e90ab46626aed6fg70038424b63f");
```

And for hashtable you can use it like below which would be probably faster and better for your use case because hashtable has O(1) get time

```
HashTable<Integer,String> table = new HashTable<>();
table.add(82,"d5c820e90ab46626aed6fg70038424b63f");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert elements at greater index than your list size.
From ArrayList api: "Throws:
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())"
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-

Instead, you could use a `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<Integer,String> mMarilynManson = new HashMap();
mMarilynManson.put(82, "ojnfonfw7");
```

Note: Java will automatically autobox your `int` primitive 82 to an `Integer` object (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (list.size() < 100) {
        list.add(null);
}
```

Add this code before any add() call. This will ensure you don't go IndexOutOfBound. Then instead of add() in your code, you can try set() method, which will replace existing null item not insert like add()